# ReactiveUI.Validation is not working on TextBox If binding has UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged (WPF, .net 5.0)

Tags: wpf, validation, reactiveui

I'm trying to learn `ReactiveUI`. Currently I'm playing with `ReactiveUI.Validation`.

I'm using a simple `TextBox`. Everything is working as expected if the binding doesn't have `UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged`. If i add it, it will hang when i type something in the textbox.
What do I miss?

Here is the MainWindow not working code:

```
<rxui:ReactiveWindow x:Class="ReactiveValidationTest.MainWindow"
                     x:TypeArguments="local:MainViewModel"
        xmlns:rxui="http://reactiveui.net"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ReactiveValidationTest"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <StackPanel Margin="50">
        <TextBox x:Name="TxtBox" 
                 Text="{Binding InputText,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"                 
                 HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"/>
        
        <TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"/>
    </StackPanel>
</rxui:ReactiveWindow>
```

The code behind:

```
using ReactiveUI;
using ReactiveUI.Validation.Extensions;
using System.Reactive.Disposables;

namespace ReactiveValidationTest
{
    public partial class MainWindow : ReactiveWindow<MainViewModel>
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            ViewModel = new MainViewModel();

            this.WhenActivated(d =>
            {
                this.WhenAnyValue(x => x.ViewModel)
                    .BindTo(this, x => x.DataContext)
                    .DisposeWith(d);

                this.BindValidation(ViewModel, vm => vm.InputText, v => v.TxtBox.Text);
            });
        }
    }
}
```

And the ViewModel:

```
using ReactiveUI.Fody.Helpers;
using ReactiveUI.Validation.Extensions;
using ReactiveUI.Validation.Helpers;

namespace ReactiveValidationTest
{
    public class MainViewModel : ReactiveValidationObject
    {
        [Reactive]
        public string InputText { get; set; }

        //ctor
        public MainViewModel()
        {
            this.ValidationRule(vm => vm.InputText,
                                txt => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(txt),
                                "Can not be null or Empty");
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Consider looking through the ReactiveUI.Validation WPF sample app, where the validations bound in XAML are known to work properly https://github.com/reactiveui/ReactiveUI.Validation/blob/main/samples/LoginApp.Wpf/Views/SignUpView.xaml#L15 We are using `{Binding UserName, ValidatesOnNotifyDataErrors=True, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}` syntax there

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have infinite loop, because you use this code:

```
this.BindValidation(ViewModel, vm => vm.InputText, v => v.TxtBox.Text);
```

Your current code reads input form control and set property, then `ValidationRule` is trying to update control, to show error message. It triggers update of input control, so again - it triggers `ValidationRule`. You use this mechanism wrong.

`BindValidation` method should be used to bind error message for given rule, which is connected with vm property to control which is designated to show that message.

You are trying to use build-in WPF mechanism which uses `INotifyDataErrorInfo` and your code is almost good. You should remove `this.BindingValidation`, because binding in `XAML` already do the job related with error message.

Comment: That solved the problem! Thanks for the detail explanation.